# Slide toggle jQuery, doesn't effect other page elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a picture on the left side of my page, and a void link that when clicked will toggle open a container for other, external links.  I need for the scroll of the web page to not be affected when the container is toggled open.  Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
*, * focus {
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    float:right;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font: 4em normal Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #aaa;
}
h2.trigger {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;

    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    width: 450px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: right;
}
h2.trigger a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float:right;
}
h2.trigger a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}
h2.active {background-position: left bottom;}
.toggle_container {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6d6d6;

    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 350px;
    clear: both;
    float:right;
}
.toggle_container .block {
    padding: 5px;

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nav li').hover(
function () {
//show its submenu
$('ul', this).slideDown(250);
},
function () {
//hide its submenu
$('ul', this).slideUp(250);

}
);
$(".toggle_container").hide();

    $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
    });

});
</script>
<h2 class="trigger"><a href="#"> Popular Links</a></h2>
    <div class="toggle_container">
        <div class="block">
            <p>links</p>
            <p>more links</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

picture is here, wasn't allowed to post the code.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean about the picture--Do you see the problem here? http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/fDFBb/

Comment: the picture scrolls down to the the bottom of the container that toggles open.  i would like for the element to be toggled open without making the picture scroll down to the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you don't want the browser to jump to the top of page? if so, instead of `href="#"` you can try putting `href="javascript:;"`

Comment: no, it's not that.  it's my image sits at the left-hand side of the page, and my toggle container sits at the right.  when the toggle is closed the top of the picture of the link to open the toggle box are at the same height, the same place on the page.  when the toggle is open, the picture slides down to meet the bottom of the container that's open, and it readjusts itself when the toggle container is closed.